Green's function for the Klein Gordon equation
The Green's function for the Klein equation is (assuming natural units $c=\hbar=1$)
$$
G(x^\mu)=\frac{-1}{(2\pi)^4}\iiiint_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-ik_\mu x^\mu}}{k_\mu k^\mu-m^2}d\omega d^3\vec{k} .
$$
Suppose $x^\mu$ is a time-like event, namely $s^2=x_\mu x^\mu>0$. We can transform the coordinates $x^\mu$ to  $x^\nu=(s,0,0,0)$. Then, we have
$$
\begin{array}{left}
G(x^\mu)=\frac{-1}{(2\pi)^4}\int_{k=-\infty}^\infty\int_{\phi=0}^\pi\int_{\psi=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\omega=-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i\omega s}}{\omega^2-\omega_k^2}d\omega k^2\sin\phi d\phi d\psi dk 
\\
=\frac{-2}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{k=0}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i\omega s}}{\omega^2-\omega_k^2} k^2 d\omega dk.
\end{array}
$$
with $\omega_k=\sqrt{k^2+m^2}$. Let's choose the contour going clockwise over both poles, as given as the definition 1 in the following figure. The $\theta(s)$ is the Heaviside step function.
$\omega$ plane" />
The Green's function is now
$$
G(x^\mu)=\frac{-2}{(2\pi)^3}\int_{k=0}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i\omega s}}{\omega^2-\omega_k^2} k^2 d\omega dk=-\frac{\theta(s)}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin(\omega_k s)}{\omega_k}k^2dk.
$$
Replace $\omega_k$ and $k$ with $m\cosh\eta$ and $m\sinh\eta$ respectively. We have
$$
\begin{array}{left}
G(x^\mu)=-\frac{m^2\theta(s)}{2\pi^2}\int_{0}^\infty\sin(ms\cosh\eta)(\sinh\eta)^2d\eta
\\=-\frac{m\theta(s)}{2\pi^2s}\left[\sinh\eta\cos(ms\cosh\eta)|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\cos(ms\cosh\eta)\cosh\eta d\eta\right]
\\=-\frac{m\theta(s)}{2\pi^2s}\left[\sinh\infty\cos(ms\cosh\infty)+\frac\pi2J_1(ms)\right]
\end{array}.
$$
Question:
There is an infinity $\sinh\infty\cos(ms\cosh\infty)$ in the equation. How can one get rid of it?
